# Will connection.cursor() as cursor create new connection?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database

If am doing the following in Django, will a new connection object be created for every query execution?

```
for query in query_list:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use a `cursor` in the first place and not Django's ORM? Django has a connection pool manager that aims to reuse connections. Furthermore due to lazyness it will only perform read queries if you need to "materialize" these.

Comment: @WillemVanOnse I need to run raw SQL queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query)
```

`with` keyword means you are using a context manager in Python, at the end of this block `connection.__exit__` is silently called and the connection is closed. Likewise at the beginning of the block `connection.__enter__` is executed.

To answer your question, yes you are opening and closing a connection for each query in `query_list`. If you want to avoid that permute the loop and the context manger, as:

```py
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for query in query_list:
        cursor.execute(query)
```